Crear en Java un ScheduledExecutorService que se ejecutara cada dia a las 12:05 AM
He creado la siguiente clase:
public class EjecucionAutomatica {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creamos un ScheduledExecutorService que se ejecutara cada dia a las 12:05 AM
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        
        //Creamos una tarea que se ejecutara las 12:05AM
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
                System.out.println("Ejecucion automatica a las 12:05 AM");
            }
        };
        
        //Programaos la tarea que se ejecute a las 12:05 AM cada día
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    
    }

}

Quiero que cada día se ejecute de manera automática a las 00:05. Pero no sé cómo poner que se ejecute a esa hora. ¿Podéis ayudarme? es la versión 8 de Java.
Un saludo.

Una primera modificación en tu código sería definir la hora de ejecución del scheduler, calcular los minutos que faltan para llegar a esa hora y ejecutarlo, repitiendo a intervalos de un día.
Sería de esta forma:
public class EjecucionAutomatica {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creamos un ScheduledExecutorService que se ejecutara cada dia a las 12:05 AM
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    //12:05 AM
    LocalDateTime inicio = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 10, 10, 0, 5);
    
    //Calcula los minutos hasta la hora de inicio
    LocalDateTime ahora = LocalDateTime.now(); 
    long delay = 0;
    if (ahora.isBefore(inicio)) {
        delay = Duration.between(ahora, inicio).toMinutes();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: ya pasó la hora de inicio");
    }
            
    //Programamos la tarea que se ejecute a las 12:05 AM cada día
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            ()->{System.out.println("Ejecucion automatica");}
            , delay, 24*60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);   
}    }

El scheduler se ejecuta a las 0:05 del día definido. Para esto se calcula lo que resta hasta esa hora (delay) en minutos, y se repite cada 24 horas.
Reemplacé task por una lambda por conveniencia, de ambas formas funciona.
